# Unable to copy postgresql table in another database

Tags: postgresql-9.1, phppgadmin

I try to copy postgresql table in another database as I write in pgAdmin 3 this query

```
$pg_dump -t pl_biz_enhanced business_catalog | psql business_catalog_enhanced
```

here pl_biz_enhanced is the table i want to copy and business_catalog is the database in which is this table

But I receive syntax error near $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an SQL query.

```
$pg_dump -t pl_biz_enhanced business_catalog | psql business_catalog_enhanced
```

The `$` is a reference to the UNIX shell prompt, which usually ends in `$`.

This is a shell command. You can't run it in PgAdmin-III.

As far as I know there's no equivalent feature in PgAdmin-III. Either do the `pg_dump | pg_restore` in the command prompt or manually do the equivalent in PgAdmin-III, which would be to dump just the `pl_biz_enhanced` table of `business_catalog` and then restore it to the separate database `business_catalog_enhanced`.

Comment: thank you - I  tried with back up and restore in 't pgadmin but it doesn't work